# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver on install

Tags: linux, xampp, driver, survey

Hi I m trying to setup limesurvey on xampp on linux . I want the setup to use msssql server on a windows box. I have successfully setup xampp and modified the config.php in application/config folder of lime survey to point to sql server. when i try to launch http://host.name.com:8080/limesurvey/admin it shrows error as below

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver

/opt/lampp/htdocs/limesurvey/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(382)

```
370 throw new CDbException('CDbConnection.connectionString cannot be empty.');
371 try
372 {
373 Yii::trace('Opening DB connection','system.db.CDbConnection');
374 $this->_pdo=$this->createPdoInstance();
375 $this->initConnection($this->_pdo);
376 $this->_active=true;
377 }
378 catch(PDOException $e)
379 {
380 if(YII_DEBUG)
381 {
382 throw new CDbException('CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: '.
383 $e->getMessage(),(int)$e->getCode(),$e->errorInfo);
384 }
385 else
386 {
387 Yii::log($e->getMessage(),CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR,'exception.CDbException');
388 throw new CDbException('CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.',(int)$e->getCode(),$e->errorInfo);
389 }
390 }
391 }
392 }
```